# Responsive Carousel With 10 columns and 5 rows infinite items

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

[Like that](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4cNPc.png)

i have multi products i want to make these products Carousel in bootstrap responsive with 5 rows and 10 columns at a time show 50 products when i click on next then show another 50 product i have unlimited product but show ata time 50 product with Carousel

```
html code it have 2 rows and 4 columns make it 5 rows and 10 columns

<div class="container">
<div class="col-xs-12">

    <div class="page-header">
        <h3>Bootstrap 3.3.0</h3>
        <p>Responsive Moving Box Carousel Demo</p>
    </div>

    <div class="carousel slide" id="myCarousel">
        <div class="carousel-inner">
            <div class="item active">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide1 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide2 --> 
            <div class="item">
                    <ul class="thumbnails">
                        <li class="col-sm-3">   
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                        <li class="col-sm-3">
                            <div class="fff">
                                <div class="thumbnail">
                                    <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/360x240" alt=""></a>
                                </div>
                                <div class="caption">
                                    <h4>Praesent commodo</h4>
                                    <p>Nullam Condimentum Nibh Etiam Sem</p>
                                    <a class="btn btn-mini" href="#">» Read More</a>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
              </div><!-- /Slide3 --> 
        </div>


       <nav>
            <ul class="control-box pager">
                <li><a data-slide="prev" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></i></a></li>
                <li><a data-slide="next" href="#myCarousel" class=""><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></i></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
       <!-- /.control-box -->   

    </div><!-- /#myCarousel -->

</div><!-- /.col-xs-12 -->          

</div><!-- /.container -->
```

CSS code

/* Global */

```
img { max-width:100%; }

a {
    -webkit-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -moz-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -ms-transition: all 150ms ease;
    -o-transition: all 150ms ease;
    transition: all 150ms ease; 
    }

a:hover {
    -ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)"; /* IE 8 */
    filter: alpha(opacity=50); /* IE7 */
    opacity: 0.6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.thumbnails li> .fff .caption { 
    background:#fff !important; 
    padding:10px
}

/* Page Header */
.page-header {
    background: #f9f9f9;
    margin: -30px -40px 40px;
    padding: 20px 40px;
    border-top: 4px solid #ccc;
    color: #999;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.page-header h3 {
    line-height: 0.88rem;
    color: #000;
}

ul.thumbnails { 
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}



/* Thumbnail Box */
.caption h4 {
    color: #444;
}

.caption p {  
    color: #999;
}



/* Carousel Control */
.control-box {
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
.carousel-control{
    background: #666;
    border: 0px;
    border-radius: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 34px;
    font-weight: 200;
    line-height: 18px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    padding: 4px 10px 0px;
    position: static;
    height: 30px;
    width: 15px;
}



/* Mobile Only */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .page-header, .control-box {
        text-align: center;
    } 
}
@media (max-width: 479px) {
    .caption {
        word-break: break-all;
    }
}


li { list-style-type:none;}

::selection { background: #ff5e99; color: #FFFFFF; text-shadow: 0; }
::-moz-selection { background: #ff5e99; color: #FFFFFF; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to redesign your Bootstrap as your own criteria. You have to make `col-sm-10 = col-sm-12` means `col-sm-10 = 100%` and then `col-sm-2` will be `20%`. I have tried to do your work. May be it will help you to solve your problem.

```
<html>
<head>  
    <style>
        @media (min-width: 768px){
        .col-sm-2 {
        width: 20.00000%;
        }}

        @media (min-width: 768px){
        .col-sm-10 {
        width: 100.000%;
        }}
        @media (min-width: 768px){
        .col-sm-10, .col-sm-2, .col-sm-6{
        float: left;
        }}

        .col-sm-2, .col-sm-10, .col-sm-6{
        position: relative;
        min-height: 1px;
        padding-right: 15px;
        padding-left: 15px;
        }
        * {
        -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
        -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
        box-sizing: border-box;
        }

        div {
        display: block;
        }

       .col-sm-6 {
    width: 50%;
}

    </style>




</head>
<body>


       <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>
           </div>

           <div class="row">

          <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>


            <div class="col-sm-6">

           <div class="col-sm-10">
                <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

               <div class="col-sm-2">
                <img src="http://placehold.it/150x80?text=IMAGE" class="img-responsive" style="width:100%" alt="Image">
                <p>Current Project</p>
               </div>

             </div>

            </div>
           </div>




</body>
</html>
```

See this in [here](http://codepen.io/blackbird36/pen/RRqwPY)

Comment: i try it nice but when i have 100 or more products then show next prevs option and show every time 50 products

Comment: Just add another row to make 50 products. I saw that other works you had done already.